# The change in domain model makes me also change DTO when I try to implement rest api. So, what is the use of DTO

Tags: asp.net, api, web

When one decides to refactor or change the domain model, one also has to change the DTO. For example, there is "Customer" class being one of the domain models then there was created "CustomerDTO" class with the purpose that if any change is done to Customer class, API willnot be broken.

But if we decide to, say, remove or rename a property in domain model, we also have to make change to DTO so why on earth should I use DTO then.

Also, DTO leads to violation of DRY principle.

Can you explain in detailed and clear way why DTO is recommended to be used with WEB API when I can achive the same by using domain model and without any middleman and just change domain model and not worry about the change that needs to be done in DTO.

Comment: the main purpose of a DTO is a separation of concerns - the object you expose to the outside world (or accept as input) need not precisely match the domain or data model. It can contain only what it actually needs to contain. Some fields may never be exposed, or maybe extra fields are accepted as input, or maybe simply the structure in which the data is presented is different. If you're doing super-simple CRUD operations then sure maybe you never have a DTO structure which deviates from the data model, but if there's any complexity at all  in your app then you might start to see differences.

Comment: " there was created "CustomerDTO" class with the purpose that if any change is done to Customer class, API willnot be broken."....that, IMO, is not the purpose of the DTO. It's true in some cases you might not need to alter the CustomerDTO - if the change is totally internal, e.g. a change to business logic, or a new internal-only field. But yes if it's a new field which you wish to expose via the API then of course you have to change the DTO. It's totally dependent on the individual circumstances of the proposed change.

Comment: Another more technical reason for using DTOs in ASP.NET Web API specifically is that if you're also using an ORM like Entity Framework to provide the data model classes, then they often contain circular references (to represent the relationship between database tables), and such references cannot be serialised to JSON because it would produce an infinite loop, whereas JSON is a linear hierarchical representation. Your question is largely a matter of opinion really, but I have given just a few examples of the potential reasons why a DTO might be a useful tool.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your attention and reply but again how by creating DTO we reduce the chance of API breaking. Secondly,  say, CustomerDTO and Customer domain model are created and then they were connected both with automapper and since automapper works on convention and what if I decide to rename or delete DateOfBirth property(which is the same in both classes) do I need to override conventions.

Comment: " again how by creating DTO we reduce the chance of API breaking."...I believe my example of where you create some internal-only field (e.g. maybe a timestamp or a "created by" field or some such thing would cover that. And..."since automapper works on convention"...it does but you can also set as many custom rules as you like. But if you delete or rename the same property in both classes, then you don't need to do anything (provided that, in the case of a rename, you rename them to the same thing in both. If you rename them differently in each class you'd need an explicit rule to map them).